# Flowtype libdefs – How can you import a type from a different libdef?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I'm trying to improve on the [`koa-router` libdefs](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/902ad5f93ffaf83b12b5ee16735c4a864c353b90/definitions/npm/koa-router_v7.2.x/flow_v0.25.x-/koa-router_v7.2.x.js) provided in the Flowtype repository.

Ideally, I would be able to do something like this:

```
import type { Middleware } from 'koa';

declare module "koa-router" {
  declare class Router {
    get(route: string, handler: Middleware): this;
  }

  declare export default typeof Router;
}
```

I basically want to use a `type` from the `koa` libdefs within the `koa-router` libdefs. However, when I try the `import type { Middleware } from 'koa';` line locally, it seems to make the type definitions break. Is there any way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: I believe you need to put that inside the `declare` block. I haven't tried it, but that's what is discussed [in this issue](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/1302)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now there's no good way to have dependencies between libdefs.
[flowtype/flow-typed#16](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/16) is the issue tracking that and [will likely be implemented in `flow-typed v3.0.0`](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/issues/1494).